# Service worker doesn't seem to update

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm following the following html5 rocks tutorial on service workers(http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/#disqus_thread) and I'm running into the issue that my service worker doesn't want to update.

I have a file called "app.js" with the following code:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('worker.js').then(function(reg) {
  console.log('◕‿◕', reg);
}, function(err) {
  console.log('ಠ_ಠ', err);
});
```

Also I have a file called "worker.js" with the following code:

```
console.log("SW startup");
var myCache = 'myapp-static-v3';
var urlsToCache = [ 
  '/',
  '/assets/style.css',
  'app.js'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  console.log("SW installed");
  // pre cache a load of stuff:
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(myCache).then(function(cache) {
      console.log("opened cache");
      return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
    })
  )
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {

  var cacheWhitelist = [myCache];

   event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }

        var fetchRequest = event.request.clone();

        return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
          function(response) {
            // Check if we received a valid response
            if(!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type  !== 'basic') {
              return response;
        }

        var responseToCache = response.clone();

        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
          .then(function(cache) {
            cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
          });

        return response;
      }
    );
  })
);
});
```

I tried updating the actual myCache variable name, switching the style.css with a different file and actually changing the content.

Anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: there's a chrome url (i forget) that you can use to reset a botched baked-in SW...

Comment: yeah it's chrome://serviceworker-internals/

I can manually reset it of course but the idea is that if I updated my file it should remove the old cache and cache the new files

Comment: when you say service worker does not seem to update, do you mean when you write a new service worker with the same name that doesn't get installed and take over, or that it keeps serving stale content(old version of style.css)?

Comment: @AkheelKM Yeah it's both. In the above file you see the following variable:
var myCache = 'myapp-static-v3';

As far as I read the tutorials and the documentation it says that if there's is any difference between the content in the service worker file it will update the service worker?

Not sure how this applies to the actual assets but I tried to rename the style.css with new content and still no success.

Comment: Hi - did you got ur answer. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

According to the documentation, its the actual file of the service worker that has to change.  What I do in my service worker update, I change the version number.  In your case, it could be `var myCache = 'myapp-static-v3';`

You can do something like semantic versioning.
`var myCache = 'myapp-static-v3.0.0'` then gets upgraded to `var myCache = 'myapp-static-v3.0.1';`